# How do I get ahold of the data that the user selected from a picker in xamarin forms? I want to use it in a switch statements

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I don't know how to get the data that the user selected from the picker.

in conflict, which one to use selectedindexchange so it tells me when user changes it's mind or selecteditem which tells me which one did the user selected.

```
public MainPage()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        drainquatity();
 }
void drainquatity()
{
        drain.Items.Add("1");
        drain.Items.Add("2");
        drain.Items.Add("3");
        drain.Items.Add("4");
        drain.Items.Add("5");
        drain.Items.Add("6");
        drain.Items.Add("7");
        drain.Items.Add("8");
        drain.Items.Add("9");
        drain.Items.Add("10");

        return;
 }

<Picker x:Name="drain" Title="Drain #" Margin="190,-30,50,0" 
"SelectedItem="drainx" />
```

i want to be able to know what the user selected, use that data to pass thru the switch statement.
drain#: pick from 1 to 10
user picks
switch (drainx)
case:1
then call this function to display only 1 entry.
case:2
call this function to display 2 entries

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [Picker docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/) explain all of this

```
// get the index/position of the selected item
// -1 means no selection
int ndx = drain.SelectedIndex;

// get the value of the selected item
// null means no selection
string item = (string)drain.SelectedItem;

// set an event handler to fire when an item is selected
<Picker x:Name="drain" Title="Drain #" Margin="190,-30,50,0" 
SelectedIndexChanged="ItemSelected" />  

protected void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}
```

Comment: it is throwing an exception system.nullreferenceexception has been thrown. Object reference not set to an instance of an object when i used this:  public MainPage()
        {
           // var drainxy = drain.Items[drain.SelectedIndex]; 
            string item = (string)drain.SelectedItem;
          

            InitializeComponent();
            drainquatity();

            switch (item)
            {
                case "1":
                    DisplayAlert(item, "switch", "K");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

Comment: //this is fired when user changes or selects new selection
        void ItemSelected(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //to get value user selected
            var drainx = drain.Items[drain.SelectedIndex];
            DisplayAlert(drainx, "selected Value", "OK");
        }  //this alert works

Comment: first, "an exception" is not helpful.  Which specific exception, and which line causes it?  Second, if you are doing this in the page constructor, then SelectedItem will be null because the user hasn't done anything yet.  That's what the SelectedIndexChanged event handler is there for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker x:Name="drain" Title="Drain #" SelectedIndexChanged="Drain_SelectedIndexChanged"/>  


public void Drain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (drain.SelectedIndex == -1) 
            {
                //Message
            } 
            else
            {                
                 string item = (string)drain.SelectedItem;
                DisplayAlert (selectedItem, "OK", "OK");
            }
        }
```